# Breaking out of an If statement if month = 12

Tags: date, if-statement, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using Crystal 2008 and have a report that runs twice a month to identify a certain set of data. The important formula is:

```
shared datevar FirstMonNext;
FirstMonNext:= (date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)+1,03)
```

It runs perfectly until I get to December, where month(currentdate)+1 equals 13.

I have tried an If statement:

```
if month(currentdate)=12 then 
    FirstMonNext:= (date(year(currentdate)+1,01,03)
else
    FirstMonNext:= (date(year(currentdate),month(currentdate)+1,03)
```

In running this (in December only), Crystal will not save the formula because it checks the else portion and the logic fails (no month starts with 13).

I have a backup report (Report for December Fail) that just has the formula

```
FirstMonNext:= (date(year(currentdate)+1,01,03)
```

so when the report fails, I switch to the second report, however I would like to future-proof the original report so anybody who follows me in this position can rest in peace. I have been unable to find a solution.

Is there a way to "break" an if statement when the "if" condition is true so that Crystal does not evaluate the "else" statement?

Comment: "Is there a way to "break" an if statement" <---- make 2 saperate if ? ( :